# TextFile into a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My code is working but I have a slight flaw, and I cant seem to be able to fix it. My code is:

```
def Identifierare():
     File = open("FulaOrd.txt","r", encoding="utf-8")
     for line in File:
                if line.strip():
                     Dict = {}
                     key, value = line.split(None, 1)
                     Dict[key] = value
                     print(Dict)

Identifierare()
```

My result is

```
{'debt': '3\n'}
{'income': '2\n'}
{'mortgage': '2\n'}
{'sale': '2\n'}
```

How do I take away the backslash n? In the original textfile, the words are written like this
debt 3
income 2
mortgage 2
sale 2

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Oh forgot to inform that it is Python!

Comment: `line.rstrip().split()`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting `line`, split `line.strip()` to take the carriage return and any other whitespace off the string first.

Comment: Hmm I tried that now, however it gave me this error.
TypeError: strip() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: But I managed to solve it now. I tried using .strip.split(None, 1) and it worked. Big thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be to just trim the whitespace characters (including the line break) from the right of the string using the `rstrip` function just before you split the line.

```
key, value = line.rstrip().split(None, 1)
```